# How to add RDoc documentation for a method defined using class_eval?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, rdoc

I am using `class_eval` to define a bunch of repetitive methods more concisely, something like this:

```
%w{greasy chunky bacon}.product(%w{flying sky poodle}).each do |a,b|
  class_eval "def #{a}_#{b}; do_something; end"
end
```

I would like all the resulting methods to be included in the RDoc documentation. Is there an RDoc directive which "manually" adds a method to the list of methods for the class? I can't find one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the sections on *Metaprogrammed Methods* and *Hidden methods and attributes* in the [RDoc documentation for `RDoc::Parser::Ruby`](http://Docs.SeattleRb.Org/rdoc/RDoc/Parser/Ruby.html).

In your case, you would do something like:

```
##
# :method: greasy_flying
# Makes grease fly.

##
# :method: chunky_poodle
# This is a really gruesome method. Ewww!
```

And so on.

Comment: Awesome, I knew there must be something like this, but I was looking in the wrong place. Thanks! +1